# Swift ios switching between listview and gridview

Tags: ios, swift

I just got into ios swift and are now trying to switch between listview and bigger listview.

What I have now is a normal listview. What I want to do is to create a button that toggles between listview and "bigger" listview eg bigger image in every list item like in Instagram.

Is this done by creating two seperate viewcontrollers?

Comment: What's a listview?  What's a gridview?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @nhgrif Sorry for my poor explenation. I mean like this: 
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mNnYHCJ9zKQ/VTCEQHiocLI/AAAAAAAAFmc/WEqC17QNyNU/s1600/List%2Bview%2Bto%2BGrid%2Bview.jpg

And my question now is what is the "right/proper" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all.
It is clearly possible to create that with two ViewControllers performing 
a Segue passing the Object selected to the next view.
Alternative , if what you are using is a ScrollView , you can use the existing zoom methods (zoomToRect).

Comment: Sorry for my poor explenation. I mean like this: 
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mNnYHCJ9zKQ/VTCEQHiocLI/AAAAAAAAFmc/WEqC17QNyNU/s1600/List%2Bview%2Bto%2BGrid%2Bview.jpg

And my question now is what is the "right/proper" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make it work is have 2 UIButton connect with 2 func within the main collectionview class as describe below

```
    // Use to define whether displaying grid view or block view
    // useful when you use nib files for cells (see the 3rd code example)
    // true by default
    var isGridView = true

    loadGridView () {
        isGridView = true

        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
             // load or setup for gridlayout 

        }, completion: nil)

        collectionView?.reloadData()
   }
```

and

```
    loadBlockView () {
        isGridView = false

        collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
             // load or setup for blocklayout 

        }, completion: nil)

        collectionView?.reloadData()
   }
```

For instance, you can visit [this article for more information](http://zappdesigntemplates.com/collectionview-flow-layout-from-grid-to-list-layout/)

!!! If you're using nib for cells, you will need to register all nibs and its class also be aware of

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell:UICollectionViewCell

        if(isGridView) {
            let gridCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomGridViewCellClass
            // some setup

            cell = gridCell
        } else {
            let blockCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomBlockViewCellClass
            // some setup

            cell = blockCell
        }

        return cell
  }
```